# JQuery making new fields required

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form that allow the user to add additional email input fields. I wanted the make those new fields required. The original single email field functions as expected but not the new ones. I have have tried two approaches with no success.
HTML

```
<form action="/(S(e5sipzkzq4cbahmey3c2f0xs))/Import/PostEmail" id="EmailForm" method="post" >     <fieldset>
        <legend>EmailViewModel</legend>
        <p>
            <input type="email" name="EmailAddresses" value=" " class="email" required="required" />
            <span class="btn_orange"><a href="#" class="remove_field">x</a></span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <span class="btn_orange"><a class="add_email_button" href="#">Add Another Email</a></span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <span class="btn_orange"><a type="submit" id="SendEmail_Button">Send Email</a></span>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**Add new input:**

```
$('.add_email_button').closest('p').click(function() {
            var html = '<p><input type="email" required="required" name="EmailAddresses" /><span class="btn_orange"><a href="#" class="remove_field">x</a></span></p>';
            $(html).insertBefore($(this));
        });
```

**Approach 1:**

```
$('body').on('click', 'span', function() {
    $('input').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('required', 'required');
    });
});
```

**Approach 2:**

```
  $('#SendEmail_Button').closest('span').click(function () {
        $('input').each(function() {
            $(this).attr('required', 'required');
        });
        $('#EmailForm').submit();
    });
```

**approach 3**

```
$('#SendEmail_Button').closest('span').click(function() {
            if ($('#EmailForm').valid()) {
                $.post('@Url.Action("PostEmail")', $("#EmailForm").serialize());
            history.go(-1);}
        });
```

Comment: What validation plugin are you using?

Comment: fiddle would help here

Comment: Aren't they required when you `insertBefore()`? Sorry I am misunderstanding

Comment: @Brian that was the idea but doesn't work

Comment: @artm I couldn't get the fiddle right, I updated the html above

Comment: On your fiddle I changed $('.add_email_button').closest('p'). to $('.add_email_button').click and it seems to add the 'required' but since the fiddle won't work I'm not sure if that's the problem.

Comment: something like [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vrFld)?

Comment: I don't think the required attribute is the problem, for some reason it is being ignored.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Jquery.Validate 1.10.0

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie using that ignore even the initial email input

Comment: I've added a third approach above that fails as well

Answer (score 1):

Try this and target the new input field added by the user in place of `input` (use a class, more specific).

```
$('body').on('focus', '.inputClass', function() {
    $(this).attr('required', 'required');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qa0ry2fk/3/

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle ?

Comment: I tried created a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qa0ry2fk/) but i'm having trouble getting the initial one to work there.

Comment: You didn't have an `class="inputClass"` in your JavaScript created input fields, in the above jsfiddle. See JSFiddle in my edited answer.

Comment: You excluded the onclick for the submit

Comment: true, but you have not way of know if the validation is working without that alert

Comment: Sure you do. The input box is outlined in red (at the very least, depending on the browser) if the validation is working. You don't need to manually submit the form if the fields are valid. The `required` attribute is supported in all modern browsers. If it the input fields are blank, it will not pass validation and will not submit, if they are not blank, it will pass validation and submit automatically.